# Случайные числа на СИ и цикл в Bash

Tags: c, bash

У меня есть собственная программа на си печатающая в стандартный вывод случайные числа от 0 до заданного в аргументе числа.**random_num**:

```
<time.h>

srand(time(NULL)); 
int rnd = rand() % number;
```

Там еще много кода, но это то, чем я обеспечиваю свой рандом.

Еще есть такой **скрипт**:

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( count=1; count<100; count++ ))
    do
        ARG=$(./random_num 4);
        if [[ "$(./a.out $ARG | ./checker_Mac $ARG)" =~ "OK" ]]; then
            echo $ARG
        else
            echo "KO"
        fi
    done
```

**a.out** - моя программа по сортировке этих самых случайных чисел. Она выдает набор команд которыми можно отсортировать их.
**checker_Mac** - чекер на правильность сортировки.

Вопрос: я хотел бы этим скриптом проверить правильность моей программы **a.out**, но запустив скрипт на 100 итераций проверяются всего 2-3 набора чисел. То ли из-за того что программа **random_num** использует время и быстро работающий **скрипт** при каждом ее запуске в переменную **ARG** кладет одни и те же числа, то ли **скрипт** не запускает **random_num** при каждой итерации цикла. Я не могу разобраться. Как мне сделать что бы на 1 итерацию **скрипта** шла проверка одного набора чисел?

[image: Фото с выводом программ]

Comment: -"быстро работающий скрипт" - Ну так вставьте оператор *sleep 1* внутрь скрипта и посмотрите - будут изменения, или нет.

Comment: Бери числа из `/dev/urandom`:  `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=100 count=1 | xxd -p -c1 | while read num; do echo $(( 16#$num )); done | sort -n`

Comment: Переменная `$RANDOM` в `bash` при каждом обращении возвращает случайное число из интервала 0 - 32767. Вам достаточно написать `ARG=$RANDOM`

Comment: Переменную `$RANDOM` можно регулировать, к примеру если нужны числа в диапазоне от 1 до 100, то вызов переменной будет следующим `echo $((RANDOM%100+1))`, а если нужно от 20 до 100, то вызывать нужно так `echo $((RANDOM%80+20))`

Answer (score 1):

Переменная `$RANDOM` в bash при каждом обращении возвращает случайное число из интервала 0 - 32767. Вам достаточно написать `ARG=$RANDOM`.

Если вам нужно 32-х битное случайное число, то можно написать `ARG=$(( (RANDOM << 15) + RANDOM ))` (на самом деле это 30 битное число, но для целей тестирования, я думаю, не принципиально).

Скрипт для проверки:

```
for (( count=1; count<10; count++ )); do
    ARG=$(( (RANDOM << 15) + RANDOM ))
    echo $ARG
done
```

Результат:

```
593935926
731044276
632282075
547207779
694639298
1063503187
101577290
930433846
49824967
```